# Optimal technique for generating an image from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

What would be a technique for generating an image from a portion of the active HTML on a page and making it available in JS?

I've looked at  [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). It traverses the DOM and uses the HTML/CSS information to build a representation/image that is then imported into the canvas. That seems like a huge performace overhead to the already intensive task I'm trying to achieve that involves a high framerate, I doubt it could be utilized for anything but the smallest of areas. If such thing is possible, I'm looking to capture the raw pixel data of an area.

Comment: The problem is that canvas is your only way to turn all those style rules into pixels that you can turn into a blob and into an image... html2canvas is quite speedy though. I used it before and it works quite well.

Comment: Does it have to be a front-end solution?

Comment: @Spokey that's right

Comment: @somethinghere that's a shame, I won't be able to use it in production anytime soon then :P I'm really surprised there aren't any methods for capturing pixel data in a browser

Comment: JavaScript cannot access pixel color on purpose. Its considered to be a security issue

Comment: There are other methods for capturing pixel data on a webpage--but none suitable for high framerate production. You can convert captured html+css to an image using PhantomJS on the server. Chrome has the desktop-capture API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture